# Measure 0 sets with Steinhaus Property

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, soft-question

I have noticed that the standard Cantor Set which has measure $0$ nonetheless has the Steinhaus Property ($A-A$ has non empty interior around $0$). On the other hand for any countable set $A$,  $A-A$ has empty interior.

My **question** is: Is the class of measure 0 sets with Steinhaus Property interesting? Is there a characterization of this class? Is there any reference?
I am asking because maybe this further division of measure zero sets into those without Stienhaus (small measure 0 sets) and those with Steinhaus (large measure 0 sets) can be useful? I understand this is a vague question.

Thank you,
Subham Jaiswal.

Comment: Off-hand I don't know a useful reference for measure $0$ sets with this property, but over the past 100 years there has been a HUGE amount published related to the Steinhaus property -- [useful google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=Steinhaus+%22Lebesgue+measure%22&filter=0). For example, even as far back as 1939 there was the extensive survey work [**Sur les Ensembles de Distances des Ensembles de Points d'un Espace Euclidien**](https://www.google.com/search?q=Piccard+%22Sur+les+ensembles+de+distances+des+ensembles%22&filter=0) **(continued)**

Comment: [On Sets of Distances for Subsets of Euclidean Space] by Sophie Piccard (1904-1990) -- Mémoires de l'Université de Neuchâtel #13, Secrétariat de l'Université, Neuchâtel, 1939, 212 pages. See [Bull. AMS review](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1943-49-01/S0002-9904-1943-07825-1/); also, according to my notes [the MR 2,129d review](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0002901) is very extensive (I don't have online access to the MR review, but I have a photocopy of it somewhere).